# Cancel click event of parent element only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I having div structure.

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    Employee Data
   <a>Click Here</a>
</div>
```

Parent div's click event is all ready registered by third party plug in, its not in control of me. Its doing some validation on that div click.

I want to perform some action on click of anchor tag 'Click Here', but don't want to perform validation, registered for div click.

But when user click 'Employee Data' it should perform validation as registered for click event.

I tried

```
<a onclick="(arguments[0]||window.event).stopPropagation();">Click Here</a>
<a onclick="(arguments[0]||window.event).cancelBubble=true;"></a>
```

But it cancel his own click event i.e anchor tags click event.

Comment: If you just didn't use inline listeners, this would be easy ...

Comment: Have you tried: `<a onclick="function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); }">Click Here</a>` ?

Comment: @AndreiCACIO Why would they have tried that? It won't work at all.

Comment: @Teemu You are right, discard that suggestion. I was thinking of this: `document.getElementById('clickHereId').onclick = e => e.stopPropagation();`. And you add an id on the anchor element.

Comment: @AndreiCACIO if i write the code is js file, the validation event triggered first and then it come to click event of anchor.

Answer (score 1):

`stopPropagation()` is exactly what you require, however you need to call it directly on the click event that was raised. You can do that using jQuery, like this:

```js
$('#parentDiv').click(function() {
  console.log('parent clicked');
})

$('#parentDiv a').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('child clicked');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentDiv">
  Employee Data
  <a href="#">Click Here</a>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use native JS like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#parentDiv').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('parent clicked');
})

document.querySelector('#parentDiv a').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('child clicked');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentDiv">
  Employee Data
  <a href="#">Click Here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I all ready tried to add click event of div and anchor. But there is one method 'validateData' which is bound with click  event of div. And that method get called before the anchor tag click event

Comment: Assuming you mean that it's added in the `onclick` attribute - remove that. You shouldn't be using those anyway. Call that function from the relevant event handler in the JS I posted in the examples.

Comment: The same div structure on other areas of page. I want to continue the default behaviour for them

Comment: Actually its grid, i had added anchor button for first column. So if i remove click event of div then other columns will get affected